# uilocalnotification without didReceiveLocalNotification, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I'm a beginner in iOS development and I'm trying to write a static library with the support for local notification. Is there a way to receive the events from the notification without didReceiveLocalNotification , didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ?
I tried:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handle:) name:UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification object:nil];
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible (yet, iOS 6.0) to include a global observer for the didReceiveLocalNotification  method.

But it is possible to create a global observer for the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

```
NSNotificationCenter* center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(notifyApplicationDidFinishLaunching:) name:UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification object:nil];

-(void)notifyApplicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"Application did finish launching: %@", notification);
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
}
```

With this observer it is possible to catch a Local/Push notification then the application is not running (it was closed or killed).

If the application is in the background, this method will not be called.